# MYSQL: Joining three tables under a condition

Tags: mysql, join

I'm looking to join three tables under a condition. Table1 is the "main" table that has the related id's to the other two tables.

I know how to make a single join:

```
SELECT name, column2
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id2 = table2.id2
```

However I am unable to connect it with a second JOIN to obtain `column3` using `table1.id3 = table3.id3`.

There is an additional difficulty as I only want to display those records where `name = $name` (a predefined variable).

**table1**

id | id2 | id3 | name

**table2**

id2 | column2

**table3**

id3 | column3

Any tips on how to connect the three statements are greatly appreciated.

Edit:

```
SELECT name, column2, column3 FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id2 = table2.id2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON table1.id3 = table3.id3
```

I've managed to join the three tables and my only issue is adding the `name=$name` condition.

I've tried

```
SELECT name, column2, column3
FROM table1
WHERE name=$name
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id2 = table2.id2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON table1.id3 = table3.id3
```

and

```
SELECT name, column2, column3
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.id2 = table2.id2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 ON table1.id3 = table3.id3
WHERE name=$name
```

so far.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What have you tried?

Comment: @Uueerdo I'm unable to add the second JOIN as well as the `name=$name` to the first JOIN statement (posted in the question). I tried adding another OUTER LEFT JOIN at the end of the first statement though that doesn't work.

Comment: It's customary/expected to show what you've tried. This helps in pinpointing the mistake, and prevents questions from looking like "do this for me".

Comment: `OUTER LEFT JOIN` works? I thought it should be `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: `OUTER` is optional by the way... _and in my opinion redundant_.

Comment: @Uueerdo I've updated the question with what works & what I tried.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I was indeed LEFT OUTER JOIN, sorry.

Comment: So what's wrong with the last query?

Comment: @Laura that last one looks right (WHERE comes after FROM and any JOINs); how are you trying to execute it?

Comment: $name indicates a php variable, but all we have seen so far is sql code. Where is the php code? Also, the name field indicates a string data type, so probably needs enclosing single quotes.

Comment: Thank you @Shadow for pointing me in the right direction.  What I was trying was `$q = "[...] WHERE name ="  . $name ;` but what actually worked was `$q = "[...] WHERE name = '" . $name . "'";` . Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: You should use a prepared query instead of substituting variables. That will solve the quoting problem and also prevent SQL-injection.